# create a list of matrices where columns are permutations based on a list

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`. The former is composed of cluster values and the latter of cluster pvalues. The elements in each list are strictly related, for example `list1[[1]]` has 13 numbers and `list2[[1]]` has 13 pvalues corresponding to each value in `list1`. Then, I have another list, `list3`, with a certain number of pvalues (in my real case there are at least 100) classified according to numbers in `list1`, i.e, `list3['1']` will have all pvalues from `list2` that corresponds to a value of `1`. Here are some examples of the objects in order to clarify the question.

```
list1
# $cluster.1
# [1] 1 2 12 58 31 41 44 24
# 
# $cluster.2
# [1] 6  56  46  44
#
# $cluster.3
# [1]   1  63  74   4 12
#
# $cluster.4
# [1]  49 112   9  34   4  76  48  18  20  64
#
# $cluster.5
# [1]  14  22  63  47  36   6  40   7   2   4  90  16  20  15  14 18  76  35
#
# $cluster.6
# [1]    1    9    1    8    2    2   51   36    3  212   33   12   88 23

list2
# $cluster.1
# [1] 0.6591487 0.8994453 0.1538042 0.6964092 0.8401874 0.3814041 0.4633218
# [8] 0.7244993
#
# $cluster.2
# [1] 0.8497138 0.5865632 0.1077595 0.6833493
#
# $cluster.3
# [1] 0.3361554 0.6120117 0.0981049 0.5463973 0.3299392
#
# $cluster.4
# [1] 0.66537320 0.92404972 0.03616409 0.20704537 0.40120409 0.68727494
# [7] 0.60326315 0.08871090 0.71780273 0.09714994
#
# $cluster.5
# [1] 0.5926167 0.4155177 0.5230090 0.3620749 0.8698867 0.2490805 0.2775648
# [8] 0.1876079 0.5346257 0.6736455 0.3626760 0.8941776 0.4278336 0.7944475
# [15] 0.6687182 0.0171974 0.2931373 0.3987727
#
# $cluster.6
# [1] 0.3222530 0.1097813 0.3014139 0.9999900 0.5232969 0.4544731 0.4342567
# [8] 0.9999900 0.5435826 0.1937477 0.1713069 0.7474790 0.1683223 0.8814443

list3[1:2]
# $`1`
# [1] 0.2977049 0.3080035 0.3445133 0.2938342 0.3630210 0.3037416 0.2841442
# [8] 0.2777617 0.3366143 0.3121525 0.2460582 0.3229141 0.3283752 0.4038269
# [15] 0.3220467 0.3059212 0.2960296 0.3747395 0.3228451 0.2894994 0.3609505
# [22] 0.3447814 0.2993272 0.3088115 0.3255970
#
# $`2`
# [1] 0.21775479 0.98620413 0.25035841 0.31131319 0.48057769 0.98633571
# [7] 0.20208590 0.39117415 0.55579118 0.23737710 0.37548844 0.20139280
# [13] 0.49689904 0.34500830 0.19796570 0.45113871 0.20210998 0.51241253
# [19] 0.49254870 0.50922946 0.20125218 0.21230656 0.23612062 0.13508699
# [25] 0.48944306
```

The `list3` is based on the two previous lists, i.e, the first element of `list1` is the number associated with the pvalue of first element of `list2`. Therefore, the `list3` includes all the pvalues corresponding to the same number, for example all the pvalues for number 2. Until now, I was interested in building a list of matrices where the elements of `list1` were substituted by *sampling* of elements from `list3` with the same number. My command to do it was:

```
list4 <- lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x, function(i, l) 
  sample(l[[as.character(i)]], 10, replace=T), l=list3))
```

And this command gave me this kind of output

```
list4[[2]]
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.7983852 0.29404183 0.2416229 0.3018420
# [2,] 0.7398054 0.41266109 0.9253389 0.3249007
# [3,] 0.1150981 0.24138907 0.4040050 0.8335943
# [4,] 0.4564887 0.28336511 0.2520307 0.5460348
# [5,] 0.2810911 0.92870457 0.6865136 0.4851188
# [6,] 0.6396584 0.68957506 0.8336891 0.1355544
# [7,] 0.3365557 0.01609222 0.2504679 0.1974983
# [8,] 0.2307067 0.99999000 0.8328432 0.6538944
# [9,] 0.9999900 0.84980684 0.5590235 0.2566799
# [10,] 0.5791690 0.27672559 0.3584696 0.8335943
```

However, now I want to build the permutations for each cluster but avoiding to sample the pvalues of that cluster in `list3`. Thus, and as an example, for `list1['cluster.1]` I'd like to remove from `list3` the pvalues from `list2['cluster.1']` and the same for the rest of clusters in `list1`.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Many thanks

UPDATE,

Following comments I will update the process to get these lists and the final desire output. These lists come from a data.frame with ~17,000 rows and 3 columns, and example looks like this:

```
 head(pvals)
#    gene        pval mac
#1   A1CF 0.896076585  26
#2  ABCC2 0.376808322 571
#3   ABI1 0.048601644  27
#4 ABLIM1 0.729589080  63
#5 ACADSB 0.001609905  50
#6  ACBD5 0.446628090  11
```

The `list3` comes from the split of column mac in the `pvals` data.frame:

```
split.mac = split(pvals, pvals[,3])
mac.pval = lapply(split.mac, '[[', 2)
pvals.order <- pvals[order(pvals$mac),]
```

Then, I generate a list containing each element at least 100 genes

```
l3 <- list()
ll1 <- length(mac.pval)
length(l3) <- ll1
set.seed(4)
for (i in 1:ll1) {
  vec1 <- mac.pval[[i]]
  jl <- 1; jr <- 1;
  while (length(vec1) < 100) {
    if(i==1 || i-jl==0) {
      vec1 <- c(vec1, mac.pval[[i+jr]])
      jr <- jr+1
    } else if (i==ll1 || jr+i==ll1 ) {
      vec1 <- c(vec1, mac.pval[[i-jl]])
      jl <- jl+1
    } else {
      vec1 <- c(vec1, mac.pval[[i-jl]], mac.pval[[i+jr]])
      jl <- jl+1
      jr <- jr+1
    } 
  } 
  l3[[i]] <- vec1  
}

names(l3) <- names(mac.pval)
list3 <- l3

clusters <- strsplit(readLines("clusters.txt"), "\t") # the output is a list with gene names
```

Then, the `list1` and the 'list2`are generated matching the`pvalues` data.frame

```
list2 <- lapply(clusters, function(x) {
  pvals[match(as.character(unlist(x)), as.character(pvals[[1]])), 2]
}) # the output is a list with the `mac` column of `pvals`

list1 <- lapply(clusters, function(x) {
  pvals[match(as.character(unlist(x)), as.character(pvals[[1]])), 3]
}) # the output is a list with the `pval` column of `pvals`
```

Finally, using the `list3` and the `list1` I obtain a list (`list4`) with number of permutations being rows and columns the number of elements in that cluster. So far, I was interested in sampling in the whole group of genes with the same `mac`, but now I would like to remove from each of the samplings the pvalues corresponding at the cluster for that sampling. 
The function I've used for permutation is this:

```
list4 <- lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x, function(i, l) {
  sample(l[[as.character(i)]], 10, replace=T)
}, l=list3))
```

Hope this update help to get an answer,

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you `dput()` your lists, and perhaps expand on your description of your desired result?

Comment: On @vpipkt could you post the process that generated these lists

Comment: My data @vpipkt is very huge, the list1 is a 2418 list with a number variable of elements (min=3 max=147), and in my case list4 has to be a list of dataframes with 10,000 rows and so many columns as elements in its corresponding list1 and 2, i.e., if list1[[2]] has 4 elements list3[[1]] will have a dim of 10,000 rows and 4 columns

Comment: I will post, @miles2know, the processed to generate these lists

Comment: Could you describe, in clear English, what is in `list3`? I cannot read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is maybe not that difficult - what is difficult is wading through your long and confusing explanation. Would this work?

```
list4 <- lapply(list1, 
  function(x) sapply(x, function(i) {
    sample_from <- setdiff(list3[[as.character(i)]], list1[[as.character(i)]])
    sample(sample_from, 10, replace=T)
}))
```

In general, you are probably going about this the wrong way. For example, why bother generating lists 1 and 2? You already have the data in your data frame, so work there.
I think what you aim to do is sample from `list3` for each unique value of `list1`. And `list3` is a bunch of pvals. So my guess is you want to do something much simpler like:

```
list4 <- list()
for (mac in unique(pvals$mac)) {
    list4[[mac]] <- sample(pvals$pval[pvals$mac==m], 100, replace=FALSE)    
}
```

Comment: this is not what I looking for, but I will award you anyway